# Configure Squid proxy server or pfsense to achieve WLAN URL logging

Tags: logging, squid, pfsense, url, transparent-proxy

Using Squid proxy server and pfsense are out of my comfort zone, I have managed to install Squid on an Ubuntu server and give it a static IP and connect to it via LAN after setting HTTP_access to allow all. My ultimate goal is just to "simply" log every URL accessed on my wireless network, Tried OpenDNS but it only displays domains and not who went where.

I believe pfsense is to only be installed on a actual server or PC as a router itself? I like simple here and was hoping I can still use my router to handle DHCP and being a router in general but possibly tell the router to forcefully use a transparent proxy? I was using an old netbook that was hard wired to my router for the Squid server but only for LAN.

Never used pfsense or MITM proxy or anything so less config the better I guess, Squid can be overwhelming. Just looking for the easiest to understand setup that I can do. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have transparent SSL filter enabled on pfSense. If you must see all URLs (even within SSL streams) you must install certificate on all your clients. See https://docs.diladele.com/tutorials/filtering_https_traffic_squid_pfsense/index.html for an inspiration (but it does web filtering and only limited logging as you require).

Comment: Will look into this, Confusing stuff for me a little bit but could I put pfsense on a laptop and hard wire that to the modem then use my router for dhcp and the AP, router forwarding traffic to pf sense after clients connect to router?

Comment: Not really; as for transparent interception your Squid MUST be running on default gateway (pfsense). So direct all your clients to pfSense and let it do DHCP and DNS and NAT and use your router as uplink for pfSense.